# Navigation between Screens but constructor is not calling

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have multiple screens in my app, I used CreatStackNavigator for navigation.
If I visit the screen second time the constructor is not getting called.

Let suppose I have four screen A,B,C & D and currently I am at A.

Then I go to C and then D screens respectively.

Now if I clicked on C again then the constructor of C is not getting called.

I used ComponentReceivedMount() also but it didn't worked.

My code is :-

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ToastAndroid.show('heeeelll', ToastAndroid.LONG);
    this.state = {
        drawerOpen: false,
        op: 1,
        cl: '#ffffff',
        swiper: this.renderSwpier,
        showSwiper: false,
        ftc: '#2c3554',
        stc: '#c8c8c8',
        firstTopcolor: 1,
        secondTopColor: 0,
        showview: true,
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React navigation has its own navigation lifecycle api available, which allows you to determine when a screen has become active.

For more information check the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html

The withNavigationFocus HOC provides an isFocused prop which allows you to determine is a screen is visible.

Example:

```js
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

class YourScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
     ...
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.isFocused && !prevProps.isFocused) {
      // Screen has now come into focus, perform your tasks here! 
    }
  }

}

export default withNavigationFocus(YourScreen)
```

Comment: Not getting exact idea , what need to do

Comment: You cannot rely on the constructor function to be called when navigation between screens, because react-navigation will manage mounting/unmounting for you. So if you want to perform certain tasks when a screen becomes visible the best way to go is to make use of the isFocused prop of react-navigation

Comment: but my data is not refreshing on call of this function

Comment: when i am navigating on same screen which method will always called like android have onResume()

Comment: @dentemm This doesn't seem to be working, prevProps.isFocused is coming to be true everytime, and thus the check fails, and it doesn't even enter the if clause

Answer (score 0):

Calling C second time will not call constructor because C is already mounted before as u called it from A and constructor is invoked when a new instance of a class is generated.
You can use componentwillmount() and componentdidmount() in place of relying on constructor.