# React-navigation: State remains preserved on press of back button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, back-button

In React-navigation, when back button is clicked state values aren't getting cleared because constructor isn't called. For e.g., Say I have 2 screens- A and B, if I switch from A to B and then back to A, state of A remains preserved. In such a scenario, how can I make sure that I call constructor or how can I call a function if I am transiting from B to A.
I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039505/navigation-between-screens-but-constructor-is-not-calling), but it didn't work, as `prevProps.isFocused` is coming to be true every time, and thus the check fails, and it doesn't even enter the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear stack when navigate to screen . Otherwise previous state won't clear . To know how to do it please see this [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html)